# R programming - How do I remove a string that appears multiple times in a text using gregexpr?

Tags: r, regex

Example:
In the following example, what I want to achieve is to remove all the sentences that begins with the word 'Henry', has the word 'new' in the middle of the sentence and ends with the word 'pen.'.

```
text = 'Henry just bought a new black pen. Henry\'s pen costs him $2. Henry buys a new blue pen.'
```

What I did:

```
result = gsub(pattern='((Henry).*(new).*(pen))+',replacement='',text)
```

What I want to achieve:

```
"Henry's pen costs him $2."
```

What I achieved:

""

I'm not too sure what went wrong in my codes, could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: The first issue is that `text` is a single string, a character vector of length == 1, rather than the 3 sentences as separate parts of a character vector. Is this example representative of what you are working with?

Comment: `gsub(pattern='Henry[^.]+new[^.]+pen\\.',replacement='',text)` gets you close for your example data. But the real issue is probably going to be that you first need to figure out how to split the text into sentences reliably, *then* you can start applying rules about the start/end of each sentence. Splitting sentences is often more complicated than just finding each `.`

Comment: @thelatemail Yup, I'm working with a data frame where each of the rows contain a paragraph of text. :/

Comment: @Marius So that was my mistake! Are there any alternative methods to solve this though? Oh ya, just to clarify. What does the [^.] in the above code suggests?

Comment: You could do something like `strsplit(text, "(?<=\\.)\\s+", perl=TRUE)` to split it apart and then try to look at it in chunks using your pattern and `grepl`

Comment: @OinkOink: `[^.]` matches any character that is not a `.`. The quick solution I posted relies on each sentence starting with `Henry` and ending with a `.`, with no `.`'s mid-sentence.

Comment: @Marius I see, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thelatemail suggested, you could first split `text` at each `.` to obtain a vector of sentences using

```
strsplit(text, "(?<=\\.)\\s+", perl = TRUE)
```

where the pattern `"(?<=\\.)\\s+"` means that we split at the optional space (`\\s+`) following a `.` (lookbehind assertion `(?<=\\.)`). Once we have done that, we can check for each sentence if it meets your criteria and filter out those that do not. Then we just need to paste the remaining sentences together again:

```
library(magrittr)
filteredText <- strsplit(text, "(?<=\\.)\\s+", perl = TRUE)[[1]] %>%
        grep(pattern = "^Henry.*new.*pen\\.$", x = ., value = TRUE, invert = TRUE) %>%
        paste(collapse = " ")
# 
filteredText
# [1] "Henry's pen costs him $2."
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize by sentence. You could approximate it by using `strsplit` with `sep = '\\.'`, but as the text scales that will fail, e.g. by not splitting on `?` or splitting `U.S.A.`. At this point, though, using a much better sentence tokenizer is not that hard at all, thanks to `tidytext`, which conveniently wraps the `tokenizers` package in a tidy framework.

You can either tokenize to sentences and then use regex:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

text = 'Henry just bought a new black pen. Henry\'s pen costs him $2. Henry buys a new blue pen.'

data_frame(text) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(sentence, text, 'sentences', to_lower = FALSE) %>% 
    filter(!grepl('^Henry ', sentence), 
           !grepl('.new.{2,}', sentence),
           !grepl('pen.$', sentence))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>                    sentence
#>                       <chr>
#> 1 Henry's pen costs him $2.
```

...or retokenize to words to use more basic comparisons:

```r
data_frame(text) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(sentence, text, 'sentences', to_lower = FALSE) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, sentence, drop = FALSE) %>% 
    group_by(sentence) %>% 
    filter(first(word) != 'henry',
           !'new' %in% word,
           last(word) != 'pen')
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#> # Groups:   sentence [1]
#>                    sentence    word
#>                       <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 Henry's pen costs him $2. henry's
#> 2 Henry's pen costs him $2.     pen
#> 3 Henry's pen costs him $2.   costs
#> 4 Henry's pen costs him $2.     him
#> 5 Henry's pen costs him $2.       2
```